# How can you see the documentation for a specific go function?

Tags: vim, go

I'm looking for a convenient way to quickly look up the documentation for different functions and/or packages in Go. My current approach is to google for say `ioutil.ReadFile`, but that is pretty slow/inconvenient.
The ideal solution would work directly in vim or maybe in a Go interpreter(suggestions?).

E.g. in Python the documentation of a function can be shown in PyDev by hovering over a function or using the ipython interpreter with e.g. `os.open?` or `help(os.open)`.

How do you view specific documentation for Go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have many possibilities:

- Browse http://golang.org/pkg/ and/or use the "Search" box, which even knows regexps!
- Run local godoc and get the same for all locally installed packages. Faster and off-line!
- Query godoc from the command line:

---

```
$ godoc io/ioutil ReadFile
PACKAGE DOCUMENTATION

package ioutil
    import "io/ioutil"



FUNCTIONS

func ReadFile(filename string) ([]byte, error)
    ReadFile reads the file named by filename and returns the contents. A
    successful call returns err == nil, not err == EOF. Because ReadFile
    reads the whole file, it does not treat an EOF from Read as an error to
    be reported.


$
```

---

- Use Rob Pike's `doc`[0].

---

```
$ doc ioutil.ReadFile
http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile
/home/jnml/go/src/pkg/io/ioutil/ioutil.go:48:
// ReadFile reads the file named by filename and returns the contents.
// A successful call returns err == nil, not err == EOF. Because ReadFile
// reads the whole file, it does not treat an EOF from Read as an error
// to be reported.
func ReadFile(filename string) ([]byte, error)

$
```

---

[0]: `$ go get code.google.com/p/rspace.cmd/doc`

Answer (score 1):

From within Vim (assuming you've installed [Go's plugin](http://golang.org/misc/vim/)), type `:Godoc <something>` and you will get the documentation without leaving the editor. You can obviously map a key to this (without argument, if I recall correctly, it searches for the token at the cursor location).

That being said, I often use [Rob Pike's `doc`](http://code.google.com/p/rspace/source/browse?repo=cmd) instead, from within Vim too (`:!doc <something>`).

Answer (score 1):

I use [godoc](https://github.com/nsf/gocode), an auto-complete daemon which works for Vim and Sublime. godoc is integrated with the [GoSublime](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime) plugin. The nice thing about godoc is it provides auto-complete for all packages. Besides auto-complete, I can press `super-., super-H` in Sublime and it gives documentation of the function I've typed in.

I also use [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash) for quick documentation. I use [DashDoc](https://github.com/farcaller/DashDoc) to quickly look something up in Dash from Sublime. There is also [dash.vim](https://github.com/rizzatti/dash.vim) that provides a plugin to Dash from Vim.

Dash only provides documentation for built-in packages, but I mostly use it for offline documentation for other things. So far it's the quickest way to bring up the HTML formatted documentation that I've found.

Answer (score 1):

you can run the following in the terminal. (Go version used is 1.22)

`go doc -src <packageName>.<methodname>`

e.g to view the documentation of `ReadAll` of io package, just type

`go doc -src io.ReadAll`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the godoc command line tool for that. `godoc os Open` will lookup `os.Open` and show only what's relevant to that function. You can turn on examples with `-ex`.

Example:

```
$ godoc os Signal

PACKAGE DOCUMENTATION

package os
    import "os"



TYPES

type File struct {
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
    File represents an open file descriptor.


func Open(name string) (file *File, err error)
    Open opens the named file for reading. If successful, methods on the
    returned file can be used for reading; the associated file descriptor
    has mode O_RDONLY. If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.
```

You can also run `godoc -http` and it will run a webserver showing you the documentation for all your packages (default at port 6060).

Take a look at the [godoc documentation](http://golang.org/cmd/godoc/). It's a great tool and it can do much more.

There is also [godoc.org](http://godoc.org/), which is basically an alternative `godoc` web frontend that automatically generates docs for 3rd party go code hosted somewhere else if provided with a go path like this http://godoc.org/github.com/golang/groupcache#Context.

Comment: I don't see the -ex flag in the godoc documentation (and it doesn't work when I try it). How/where would I use it?